# Strange "TransportError" after updating googlemaps python package

Tags: python-2.7, google-maps, reverse-geocoding, google-maps-static-api

I had installed a version of the googlemaps package for python 2.7 and it was perfectly working. After updating the package when I try to run the same code I get the message

```
TransportError: [('system library', 'fopen', 'No such file or directory'),
 ('BIO routines', 'BIO_new_file', 'no such file'), 
('x509 certificate routines', 'X509_load_cert_crl_file', 'system lib')]
```

and I don't have a clue of what it may be. I tried to roll back to a previous version of the package but the error still remains. 
The code I am trying to run is a very standard piece of reverse geocoding, something like:

```
import googlemaps

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key="my_key_here")

reverse_result = gmaps.reverse_geocode((lat,lon))

for result in reverse_result:
    print(result["types"], result["formatted_address"])
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved simply by uninstalling/reinstalling the package, but I'd love to know what was and what caused the error.